# Dictionary that counts occurrences of its items

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I'd like to create a [`dictionary`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in python that automatically counts the repetitions of its elements:

when an element that is not contained is added it should insert it with corresponding value `1`, if the same element is inserted again it will increment its counter.

Is there a more elegant / compact way to implement this dictionary rather than the following?

```
if var in myList:
    myDictionary[var] += 1
else:
    myDictionary[var] = 1
```

Comment: One that's not in the answers: `myDictionary[var] = myDictionary.get(var,0) + 1`.  But really don't reinvent the wheel, use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: @roippi - what is the main difference between `collections.Counter` and `collections.defaultdict`?

Comment: the answer won't really fit into a comment box, but `Counter` is more performant.  You can feed it a generator expression or an iterable, and it internally loops *in C code* to do the counting.  On the other hand you still need to write an explicit `for` loop (slow, verbose) with a `defaultdict`.  `defaultdict`s are still great when you need to accumulate something in a more complex manner than just counting.

Comment: @roippi - thks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For counting elements [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is great.

```
from collections import Counter

counted=Counter(iterable)
```

You can use dictionary like items:

```
>>> myDict=dict(a=1,b=2,c=3)
>>> myDict
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> Counter(myDict)
Counter({'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1})
```

Or lists or other iterables:

```
>>> Counter('aabbccaabcaaa')
Counter({'a': 7, 'c': 3, 'b': 3})
```

For clarification, you have:

```
if var in myDictionary:              # loops over the KEYS of myDictionary
    myDictionary[var] += 1
else:
    myDictionary[var] = 1
```

Assuming that `myDictionary` is indeed a dictionary, there won't ever be any repetition; there is only one key of any type.

---

*Edit*

Based on your comment, a dict comprehension is useful (Python 2.7 or 3+)

```
>>> myDict={'a':[1], 'b':[1,2], 'c':[1,2,3]}
>>> {k:len(v) for k, v in myDict.iteritems()}
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

With defaultdict:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dd=defaultdict(int)
>>> for k, v in myDict.iteritems():
...    dd[k]=len(v)
... 
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2})
```

Counter (with a list comprehension):

```
>>> Counter([(k,len(v)) for k, v in myDict.iteritems()])
Counter({('a', 1): 1, ('b', 2): 1, ('c', 3): 1})
```

Or, just use the `dict` constructor with a generator:

```
>>> dict((k,len(v)) for k, v in myDict.iteritems())
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

The final one, just a straight `dict` with a generator (or lc), is probably the most 'Pythonic' in this case.

Comment: my bad. I didn't mention part of my problem in the question, I'll edit it...I have a dictionary of lists and every list has a different length which is what I want to count (how many different values for the length).

Comment: also can I ask you what is the main difference between `collections.Counter` and `collections.defaultdict` in terms of when to use one or the other? thks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
d[var] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
count_dict = defaultdict(int)  # creates an int() for missing element, which is 0

count_dict['foo'] += 1
print count_dict['foo']  # prints 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections

c = collections.Counter([1,2,1,1,1,1,2])

print c

c[1] += 1
c[2] += 2
c[3] += 1

print c
```